# Set Image for cell with Reactive Cocoa

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

Im trying to fill my cell values with signals from View Model class:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([self.viewModel.dataArray count] >4){

    // Text
    cell.titleLabel.text = [[self.viewModel.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"title"];

        NSString *urlString = [[self.viewModel.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"thumbnailImage"];

        NSLog(@"Called n times");
    // Image
    [[[self.viewModel loadImageWithString:urlString]
                    deliverOn:[RACScheduler mainThreadScheduler]]
                    subscribeNext:^(UIImage* x) {

                        cell.myImageView.image = x;
                    }];

    }


    return cell;

}
```

Title is filling good for every cell, displaying correctly. But image is set only for last cell, and it blink 5 times (number of images get from jSON) very fast, and finish for last image.

What piece of puzzle did i miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using 'cell.myImageView.image=x;' is creating problem, look for other option of setting image at the indexpath (getting UITableViewCell from it again)